# Stupid usb linux question

Tags: boot, live-usb

OK, I know this is a stupid question, but I don't know and can't find the answer. I have a windows machine. I want to run a copy of ubuntu linux off a usb drive with persistence.

1. I have used pendrivelinux usb installer to put a usb distribution onto the usb drive.
2. At bootup it asks whether I want to "try linux" or "install linux"

My question is if I choose to install linux, will it be installed to the usb drive I am using (desired), or will it overwrite windows on the hard drive (undesired)?

Comment: The install wont go to the same USB you are booting, but you can select another USB for the installation target. A "persistent" installation is usually referring to a type of install media, so the "try" will save your wireless, desktop settings, etc.  A full install to another usb will do all that, but the term persistence is usually not used for that case, it's just a normal install.  Which do you want?  Adding persistence to the boot media has become harder with recent releases, so "try" the boot media, and see if your desktop (background, etc.) is saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose install Ubuntu, it will install Ubuntu in the hard drive. If you choose Try Ubuntu, you will not overwrite your Windows Installation. Try to use [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) for this purposes, it will give you the option to create a persistence file which will save your modifications in the live media, just specify the size in MB where it says "Space used to preserve files across reboots (ubuntu only)".

Comment: That is just what I wanted to know. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Enjoy your new Ubuntu!. Best regards.